# SAML implementation in java

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I was designing a very simple SSO (single sign-on) process and it should be implemented in SAML 2.0. Please guide me which jar file required  for it & steps for implementing  Service provider(SP) of SSO-SAML.

-Tejas

Answer (score 4):

In a common case like SSO with SAML I would recommend using a SAML product and not do the coding yourself. [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) is a free and open source solution for SAML.

If you need to build it yourself I would recommend using [Spring SAML module](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml) or the [OpenSAML library](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home), but these may give you more work. If you end up using OpenSAML I have a book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), introducing the SAML and the OpenSAML library.

I also have a blog with [blogg with many examples](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/).

Comment: I am using spring-security-saml demo code as service provider.How to redirect request to controller after successful login? Currently after successful login it is redirecting to root path of application.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Stefan - more possible ways to achieve this here:

[SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Note the two links at the top.